# Stay within month knowing admission date and discharge date

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I need to work out how many days patients were in the hospital each month using the admission date and discharge date data.

I have a formula I need to create which has many possibilities. Example rows (US formatted dates):

```
Admission Date  |Discharge Date  |Stay within month Oct 2016| Stay within month Nov 2016|  Stay within month Dec 2016|
11/03/2016      |11/17/2016      |  0                       | 15                        |  0                         | 
10/02/2016      |12/17/2016      |  22                      | 30                        |  17                        |
12/03/2016      |01/01/1990      |  0                       | 0                         |  19                        |
09/03/2016      |01/01/1990      |  31                      | 30                        |  31                        |
11/05/2016      |01/01/1990      |  31                      | 5                         |  0                         |
12/21/2016      |01/01/1990      |  31                      | 30                        |  21                        |
```

01/01/1990 means that the patient is still in the hospital. 
I can't type all the dates but, these columns will extend all the way to the month Dec 2018.

There are over 100 records so you can imagine why I want to automate this.

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2):

Change your `Stay within month Oct 2016` to the first of each month, `10/01/2016`.  Then you can format the Date `MMM YYYY`

[image]

Then put this in C2 and copy over and down:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((ROW(INDEX($A:$A,$A2):INDEX($A:$A,IF($B2=DATE(1990,1,1),TODAY(),$B2)))>=EOMONTH(C$1,-1)+1)*(ROW(INDEX($A:$A,$A2):INDEX($A:$A,IF($B2=DATE(1990,1,1),TODAY(),$B2)))<=EOMONTH(C$1,0)))
```

[image]

Comment: hi Scott, thanks very much for creating that magic formula! It works perfectly apart from for these records: 
Admission Date   Discharge Date Oct-16 Nov-16 Dec-16
11/5/2016                    1/1/1900             31    5           0
12/21/2016             1/1/1900             31   30          21
Basically, in the case where the admission date is after the column month AND the discharge date is 1/1/1990 the formula fails

Comment: I've added 2 more records on the image - that's what the formula shows, which it shouldn't